# Envoy Lua Local Script File

Tags: lua, envoyproxy

I am trying to implement lua script into an evnoy configuration file
What I want is to write my lua code within a local lua file and then scpecify my script file inside the envoy configuration file

This is my yaml file:

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - address:
        socket_address:
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 10000
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
            typed_config: 
              '@type': "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager"
              stat_prefix: http_proxy
              route_config: 
                name: all
                virtual_hosts:
                  - name: allbackend_cluster
                    domains: 
                      - '*'
                    routes:
                      - match: { prefix: "/"}
                        route:
                          cluster: cluster_wackopicko
              http_filters:
                - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                - name: envoy.lua
                  typed_config:
                    "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua
                    inline_code: |
                      function envoy_on_response(response_handle)
                        body_size = response_handle:body():length()
                        response_handle:headers():add("response-body-size", tostring(body_size))
                        response_handle:headers():add("foo", "bar")
                      end

  clusters:
    - name: cluster_wackopicko
      connect_timeout: 1s
      lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: cluster_wackopicko
        endpoints:
        - lb_endpoints:
          - endpoint:
              address:
                socket_address:
                  address: 127.0.0.1
                  port_value: 8081
```

What I need to change in this config file to export the lua code to external file which will be located in /envoy/lua/scripts/ folder on my ubuntu server ?

Answer (score 0):

##### Envoy >= 1.23.0

Since Envoy v1.23.0 ([and this PR](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/pull/22125)), you can define your script in `default_source_code`. See [documentation](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.23.0/api-v3/extensions/filters/http/lua/v3/lua.proto#extensions-filters-http-lua-v3-lua).

Example:

```lua
-- /envoy/lua/scripts/myscript.lua

function envoy_on_response(response_handle)
    body_size = response_handle:body():length()
    response_handle:headers():add("response-body-size", tostring(body_size))
    response_handle:headers():add("foo", "bar")
end
```

```yaml
name: envoy.filters.http.lua
typed_config:
  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua
  default_source_code: 
    filename: /envoy/lua/scripts/myscript.lua
```

##### Envoy < 1.23.0

With older versions, you can use `source_codes` with `filename`. See [documentation](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.22.2/api-v3/extensions/filters/http/lua/v3/lua.proto#envoy-v3-api-field-extensions-filters-http-lua-v3-lua-source-codes).

However, you have to add `inline_code`. [This is a known issue](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/14030).

Example:

```lua
-- /envoy/lua/scripts/myscript.lua

function add_headers(response_handle)
    body_size = response_handle:body():length()
    response_handle:headers():add("response-body-size", tostring(body_size))
    response_handle:headers():add("foo", "bar")
end
```

```yaml
name: envoy.filters.http.lua
typed_config:
  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua
  inline_code: |
    require("envoy.lua.scripts.myscript")

    function envoy_on_response(response_handle)
      add_headers(response_handle)
    end
  source_codes:
    myscript.lua:
      filename: /envoy/lua/scripts/myscript.lua
```

Comment: I have change the yaml as you said and I go the error
Proto constraint validation failed (LuaValidationError.InlineCode: value length must be at least 1 characters): source_codes {
  key: "cwaf.lua"
  value {
    filename: "/home/radware/lib/envoy_geoip.lua"
  }

Comment: @Daniel I have updated my answer with Envoy v1.23.0 and Envoy < v1.23.0. Hope that helps.

Comment: when I try to install envoy with this article it always install version 1.18.2.p0
https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/start/install

do you have any procedure for intall a fresh 1.23 or maybe upgrade procedure ?

Comment: There are probably outdated versions in the repos. 1.23.0 is pretty new (released 2022-07-15). Are you on Linux (what distribution?) or MacOS? I am personally using Docker images to use the latest versions of Envoy.

Comment: Ubuntu server 20.04 and I try to install envoy regularlly (not insde a Docker images)

Comment: Envoy packages in Tetrate repo are outdated (https://cloudsmith.io/~tetrate/repos/getenvoy-deb-stable/packages/). I'm afraid that the only solution for now is to build yourself the latest release of Envoy. Or maybe you can extract the binary and the other folders used by Envoy from the Docker image based on Ubuntu and copy it on your host? (not sure it'll work).